# Why is Vscode Cmd+R Start Debugging doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to assign `Cmd+R` to `Debug/Start Debugging` on Vscode (1.33.1).

`Cmd+R` had an initial assignment to `Reload Window` so I removed it. Then when I pressed `Cmd+R` it started waiting for the second keystore. I went to keyboard shortcuts again and removed all two-key occurances that were present (that were causing a wait for a second keypress after `R`).

Now when hit `Cmd+R`, I see the `Debug / Start Debugging` highlight briefly on menu bar, which means that the menu item is invoked:

[image: start debugging]

However, nothing happens. It doesn't start debugging (nor waits for a second keypress) When I manually click the same command, it starts perfectly.

What is going on, and how can I make my key assignment work?

Comment: It is weird, I changed mine and it seems to be working correctly. Sorry if this is something stupid, but have you tried assigning it to a different shortcut? And maybe restarting your ide?

Comment: @Corné no it's not a stupid question. I've just assigned it `cmd+option+shift+1` temporarily, and it worked. I still have no idea why `cmd+r` doesn't work as it's the shortcut that I'm used to from many other apps such as Xcode. (and yes, I've restarted Vscode)

Comment: @Corné super weird. after reassigning it to `cmd+r`, it worked. I have no idea why that was the case.

Comment: hmm, that is weird...We'll, I am glad that you've sorted it out. Do you mind if I post it as an answer in order for you to mark answered?

Comment: @Corné sure! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments above, the command was assigned to another shortcut (something other than `Cmd+R`), and it worked. It was also suggested to restart the IDE.

Note: After the the command was reassigned, it was changed back to `Cmd+R` and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Super weird. After following Corné's suggestion I've assigned it to something else (`cmd+option+shift+1`). It worked. Then, I've changed it back to `cmd+r` and it suddenly started working with `cmd+r` too. It was probably a nasty Vscode bug.